# Before Class Method of JUnit not called in correct order

Tags: junit

I'm new to JUnit and was learning the various annotations. The code below however is giving me output that seems wrong

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Test;

public class SampleTest {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() {
        System.out.println("Before Class"); }

    @AfterClass
    public static void afterClass() {
        System.out.println("After Class"); }

    @Before
    public void before() {
        System.out.println("Before"); }

    @After
    public void after() {
        System.out.println("After"); }

    @Test
    public void testAreFirstAndLastNCharactersTheSame() {
        System.out.println("testAreFirstAndLastNCharactersTheSame");}

   @Test
   public void testTruncateAinFirstNPositions() {
        System.out.println("testTruncateAinFirstNPositions"); }
}
```

The output I get is

```
Before
testTruncateAinFirstNPositions
After
Before
testAreFirstAndLastNCharactersTheSame
After
Before Class
After Class
```

This seems wrong as the "Before Class" print should be first. Am I doing something wrong? My Junit version is 4.12. I ran the above piece of code on Intellij.

The actual output screenshot is below

[image]

Comment: I don't see why that might be happening. I ran the code on mine and it worked as expected, so in the order : beforeclass, before, test, after, before, test, after, afterclass. i am running the same version of junit

Comment: I just added the screenshot of the output. Have a look please

Comment: i have not used intellij, I dont know if that might be doing something. have you tried it on eclipse?

Comment: I also run this code in IDEA and it works well. I suggest you to debug your code step by step to find out the real reason.